# Possibly loss of keychain access

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, entitlements, app-transfer

There are few similar questions on SO, but it's not completely clear still...

Recently we transferred our app to different AppStore account. Now when we try to submit app update to new account, itunesconnect produces the warning:

"The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['XXXXXXXX.id.bundle] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['YYYYYYYY.id.bundle']. This will result in a loss of keychain access."

We really use keychain to store api authorization information. And now we concern that after all current users upgrade the app, they'll lost their authorization and will be signed out.

Can someone confirm our concerns?
I tried to reproduce the case: I've installed current version of the app from AppStore (this app has old application prefix), signed in, then I installed test build via TestFlight (it has already new app prefix), and after launch the app no sign out has happened.

Comment: you may need to create an application group, which can be accessible by multiple bundle ids at the same time, and then you may be able to be free to change the bundle id on the fly, because your app will be accessing to the 'shared' keychain groups, rather than keychain container which is associated to a bundle id directly – and you won't face any data loss.

Comment: Is it gonna work with different AppID prefixes?

Comment: that is the exact point of creating application groups.

Comment: This kind of sharing doesn’t require interaction with or permission from the user, but limits sharing to apps that are delivered by a **single development team**. [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps)